# Which one is best for chat app ? Web socket or Send request every 3 seconds

Tags: node.js, react-native, server, socket.io

I am making chat app on react-native. I am using socket.io for this but socket.io sometimes not working successful. I would like to change send request to server side every 3 seconds.

I just send request for one chat id

Which one is best? If i use send request in every 3 seconds , will happen any problem from server side

Answer (score 2):

Maybe long polling (not polling, it is different behaviour, with long polling an api call can stay pending until response is available) is an option but WebSocket are far preferable.
Responses are faster, it costs less resources serverside, less bandwidth, you can subscribe to multiple streams and so on.

Here you can valutate some metrics:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Ref: https://blog.feathersjs.com/http-vs-websockets-a-performance-comparison-da2533f13a77

Comment: Thank you for comment sir. My socket.io problem is sometimes send same message 5 times , because of I prefer to change socket.io

Comment: This is probably a frontend problem where you add multiple listeners on the same event, I build 2-3 chat every year so I can confirm socket.io will make your life easier.

Comment: Thank you for everything :)

Answer (score 1):

socket.io scales better, and has better performance, than any polling HTTP request mechanism. When working well, it will also have faster response times than 3 seconds - it may not seem long, but actually it may be noticeable to users.

If your chat app is for a low number of users, then a polling mechanism is easier to implement and should work just fine.

If you intend to scale your application to a large number of users, you will need socket.io or a similar subscribe/push mechanism to connected clients.

Comment: Thank you for comment sir. My socket.io problem is sometimes send same message 5 times , because of I prefer to change socket.io

Comment: @A.Emre: That is a different question. If you want to solve it, you should ask a new question and give some details about the problem - when it occurs, what you've looked at to try and solve it yourself. The current question is now answered.